# Pandas to_excel command, determine target column

Tags: python, pandas

This block takes a vector DATA and writes it as the first column of an excel sheet

```
wf = pd.DataFrame({'first column': DATA})
wf.to_excel(f"MyExcelSheet.xlsx", index=False)
```

How should I change this so that DATA is written as the second column instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding a start column offset:

```
wf.to_excel('MyExcelSheet.xlsx', startcol=1, index=False)
```

(defaults starting column in 0)

See  [panda docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) for more options.